# how to do this base64encode in xml element value using string manipulation function in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, base64, xor

I have this xml file, and I need to fill out the `hash` element with the following formula

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
   <time>xxxx</time>
   <id>12345678</id>
   <code>abcd</code>
   <hash>base64encoded(a XOR b)</hash>
<data>
```

with

```
a = {time} + {last 4 digit of id} => xxxx5678
b = {reversed last 4 digit of id} + {code} => 8765abcd
```

Anyone can point me How I can do this using XSLT ? 
No idea at all about this problem.

Really appreciate your help.

Thanks very much.

Kind Regards,
LL

Answer (score 0):

To Encode to Base64 see this [link](http://arcanecode.com/2007/03/21/encoding-strings-to-base64-in-c/)

Then use [XPath](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333/da) to fill out the hash element

Sorry for the short answer. Hope it is still helpful